# How to remove CE-MAGETWO-67805 Patch - Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, pattern-library

I am using Magento **2.1.6** and I need to upgrade to **2.1.7**, and before I can do that, I need to remove the `CE-MAGETWO-67805` patch and my problem is how to remove the patch?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you've applied that patch.

For example if you've used `git apply <patch.file>` just run: `git apply -R <path to CE-MAGETWO-67805.patch>`